# How to retrieve the difference of two tsvectors in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, tsvector

I have two varchars fields, I would like to get an array of words, that are present in one of them, and not present in another, i.e. :

```
old_text := to_tsvector("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
new_text := to_tsvector("The slow brown fox jumps over the quick dog at Friday")
-> new words: ARRAY["slow", "at", "Friday"] ( the order of words doesn't matter )
```

I tried fiddling around with ts_vectors, but no luck..
Any other functionality in postgres, that supports something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to involve text search, have a look at [`ts_parse()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/textsearch-debugging.html).

```
SELECT token
FROM ts_parse('default', 'The slow brown fox jumps over the quick dog at Friday')
WHERE tokid != 12 -- blank
EXCEPT
SELECT token
FROM ts_parse('default', 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog')
WHERE tokid != 12 -- blank

-- will give you

"token"
--------
'slow'
'at'
'Friday'
```

Or, you can use regular expressions for that:

```
SELECT *
FROM regexp_split_to_table('The slow brown fox jumps over the quick dog at Friday', '\s+')
EXCEPT
SELECT *
FROM regexp_split_to_table('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', '\s+')
```

At the end, use `array_agg()` to accumulate the results into an array, if necessary.

Comment: +1 but it is regexp_split_to_array and not regexp_split_to_table

Comment: Thanks, I go try them, and see which one is faster.

Comment: @Alexandros both of those are existing functions. But there are no array difference function built-in, that's why i choose the set-returning one.